Testing whether two x-y plots are significantly different
I have 5 case studies (SF=1, SF=2, SF=3, SF=4 and SF=5) for which I measure a quantity called xP at different locations (cells). The data is shown in the attached image. My reference case is SF=1, and I want to determine how well the other cases match the reference case. I would like to determine which cases are significantly different and therefore unacceptable. Looking at the graphs, SF=2 seems reasonably similar, SF=4 and SF=5 seem very different and SF=3 is somewhere in between. How can I quantify this?
Thanks in advance for any tips!

Edited upon request
Here is some more information about what is measured, and how:
I am performing simulations of discharging a mixture of two material components (P and S, 50-50 by mass) from a hopper into a container, such that a heap is formed. I am investigating to what extent the mixture is homogeneous in the container. The container is divided into 10 cells (see figure below for an illustration, where 4 cells are shown) and I measure the mass fraction of component P (referred to as “xP”) in each cell. Theoretically, the value of xP can range from 0-1 in each cell, and the heap is perfectly homogenous if xP=0.5 in each cell. This investigation is done for 5 cases:

SF (scaling factor) = 1: here, the material components have their original size distributions.
SF = 2, 3, 4, 5: here, the particle sizes are up-scaled by a factor of 2, 3, 4, 5.

So basically, I am investigating the scaling effects on the mixture homogeneity after forming a heap.
The simulations for SF = 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are each repeated 3 times, so the error bars in the plots represent the standard deviation of xP.


Welcome to Cross Validated! As those who visit this site have many different backgrounds, it would help if you could please edit the question to say more about what these values represent. What is a "Cell" in this context, what specifically do you mean by "case studies," and what does "xP" represent? Do the different "case studies" represent measurements on the very same "cells"? Those details are important if you want to get a helpful answer. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Also, when you describe the "xP" measurements, please say something about the differences in values that might be of practical importance. With enough observations even small differences of no practical consequence can be found to be "statistically significant." For example, does a difference between values of 0.48 and 0.50 in a "Cell" matter?

+1 for the request to provide additional details. Are the measurements for the same cell somehow correlated (e.g. the measurements are made on the same "unit"), or are they independent? Can we aggregate all the measurements for a given SF (i.e. treat them all as independent measurements of the same $SF_i$? IS each cell a random "subject", or are they different conditions?

@EdM, thanks for your response. Please see the edited post. xP can vary from 0-1, so a difference between 0.48 and 0.5 is not very important.

@jginestet thanks for your response! Please see the updated post, does the new information answer your questions?

Thanks for the additional details. Two more questions. 1) Is it true to say that the grand average xP over all 10 cells will always be .5, regardless of the SF? 2) Is it fair to say that your goal is to find the SF which makes xP over all 10 cells as close to .5 as possible?

@jginestet: (1) No, the average is not necessarily 0.5, that is only true for the "ideal" case and (2) No, the goal is to determine how different the plots for SF = 2, 3, 4 and 5 are to SF=1.

For this data set you've already answered the practical question: the largest discrepancy from the ideal value of 0.5 is 0.48, and you said in a comment that the difference between 0.5 and 0.48 "is not very important." I'm pretty sure that formal tests would document a "statistically significant" difference among your 5 values of SF, but that's essentially irrelevant if the difference doesn't matter in practice.
There are many ways to quantify differences among distributions. In this case, it probably makes the most sense to treat your ideal value of xP = 0.5 for all values of Cell as the reference case, and evaluate each of the SF levels against that.
A simple and easy to explain approach is to determine the mean-square deviation from the ideal 0.5 value for each SF level. For each SF level and simulation, calculate the mean-squared deviations between the observed xP for each cell and the value of 0.5, and sum those up over all the cells. If the numbers of particles differ greatly among cells (as your illustration suggests) you could consider a weighted average of the mean-squared deviation values, weighting each cell by the number of particles in it. Then report, for each SF level, the average (weighted) mean-square deviations over the 3 replicates.

Dear @EdM, thank you for your response. What do you mean by "number of objects"?

@granulist I meant "number of particles" in each cell. I'll edit the question to clarify.

If your goal is to make xP as close to 0.5 over all 10 cells, there is not much to add to @EdM's answer. Basically this is a RMS error calculation (and yes, you could/should weigh the bins by their "size" -number of particles. And you would use a $\chi^2$ test to check significance.
But your comments say that this is not what you want to find out (the SF which minimizes this RMS error). Instead you want to find out if/how the various $SF_i$'s differ from $SF_1$.
One way is to compute a similar RMS error, but looking instead at the differences from $SF_1$ (and not .5), bin by bin. And still use a $\chi^2$ test to check for significance. That will tell you which $SF_i$ is least different (in a RMS sense) from $SF_1$, and whether that difference is significant. And you can still weigh by the "size" of the bin.
These RMS error methods "lump" all the bins together, which may or not be fine for your use. Another approach, which also lumps all bins together, would be to use a 1-way ANOVA; 5 factors (the $SF$'s), 30 observations for each factor (so decent power). Use Dunnett's method to only compare to $SF_1$. This will tell you which $SF$ is significantly different from $SF_1$, on average (no longer RMS error!).
You can even do a bit better (maybe?). Before you combine all bins, add to the values in each bin a constant which make $SF_1$ have mean of 0.5 in that bin (or mean of 1, or 0, or...; that would not change anything. You are basically normalizing all bins to $SF_1$, since this seems to be your "gold standard"). The above compared to the grand mean of $SF_1$ accross all bins. This now compares to the mean of $SF_1$, bin by bin.

thanks a lot for these great ideas, I will look into all the different options!
